# Generating SE friendly URL .htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a URL which get file name through get method and display it on the page.

```
tvchaska.info/i/
```

this is the page and when u click any image it will go to say

```
http://tvchaska.info/i/output.php?i=http://brothertattoo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Sexy-Girl-Tattoo.jpg
```

I want my this URL to be rewritten as tvchaska.info/i/Sexy-Girl-Tattoo.html

I tried following rule but it is not working

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /output.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Can any one plz help me to attain this plz?

Comment: Please *oh please*, **oh please** say PLEASE instead of plz. My eyes are burning.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen you page, I'll give you the answer only if I can meet 3 girls of your page IRL! Just kidding.

Here's the solution:

-1: all your link don't have to be like:

`/i/output.php?i=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_R2Wo1mDtuko/TGzOFQEhpoI/AAAAAAAACAA/Na-WQ1xe7dY/s1600/sexy.jpg`

but something like:

`/i/1.bp.blogspot.com/_R2Wo1mDtuko/TGzOFQEhpoI/AAAAAAAACAA/Na-WQ1xe7dY/s1600/sexy.jpg`

-2: once you've modified your site, apply those rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/i/(.*)+ /i/output.php?i=http://$1
```

This will do the job.

Olivier

Comment: :) I wish i cud have them :) Your given solution is not working still :(

Comment: why isn't my solution good? please ("plz" lol) be more explicit: is there a 404, a 500, or anything?