# htaccess.. SE freindly URLs

Tags: php

Ok, I have read the other questions, and have tried the options provided, but none seem to work for me. so, here we go this is what I currently have

http://www.desmoinesdrinks.com/?view=ads&catid=2&subcatid=6&cityid=1&lang=en

and this is what I want

http://www.desmoinesdrinks.com/1/posts/2_Clive/6_Down_Under/

my htaccess file is pretty big, but I can post it up if anyone wants to see it.

Comment: You should post what you've tried, and what did/didn't work.  We don't need the whole file, just relevant parts.

Comment: its untrue that theses urls are any more search engine *friendly* any more.

Comment: @Dagon Maybe yes, but the readability of URLs is still considered a part of SEO. If not actually for search engines, at least for users.

Comment: well as SE = search engine, that clearly makes no sense. And when what the last time you actully typed in a url vs bookmarks and links.

Comment: Please see the comments below to see what I've tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/posts/(.*)_(.*)/(.*)_(.*)/$ ?view=ads&catid=$2&subcatid=$4&cityid=$1&lang=en [L]
```

Comment: I tried the fix in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed  and this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178690/generating-se-friendly-url-htaccess-mod-rewrite

Comment: Uhh... have you tried what I wrote here? It should probably work.

Comment: This is my current RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html  
/index.php?view=showad&adid=$7&cityid=$1 [QSA] that is just one of 22 used in my htaccess. So I cant just change one and see if it works, I need to know what is changed, and why, so I can modify all of them. I do notice what has changed, but I dont know what the [L] or if the lang=en is needed

Comment: The [L] just means that if the rewrite rule can be applied, it should stop parsing: http://www.easymodrewrite.com/notes-last

Comment: As for the rule itself, its just trying to retrieve a lot of values ($1-$5) and rewriting them into the other URL

Comment: So I replace this:  ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-][^/]*)?\.html  /index.php  with this:  ^(.*)/posts/(.*)_(.*)/(.*)_(.*)/$   in each script?

Comment: I dont know the rest of your .htaccess/script, but yes, I think thats what you should do (just try it; if it doesnt work, revert the changes)

Comment: they are basically set up the same, some just show catid some show the whole string depending on how the user access the ad.. I'll try it now

Comment: it did not work. Here is the original htacess file http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=364596&c=8362766 and here is the one I tried modifiying http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=364595&c=5934608  thanks for your help

Comment: Oh no, you should only replace the line you mentioned in your question  with the one I gave in my answer

Comment: well, every line is dependent on the next, so changing one will not work

Comment: I'm not gonna rewrite your complete .htaccess file... I helped you out with this one, please accept the answer (because it does answer your question) and try to figure out how to change the others yourself.

Comment: No, your answer is based off the original URL, which is incorrect. Your script contains the ID numbers of each category, subcat, ad and city IDs, which are not present in the htaccess file